# Multinomial logistic loss gradient and hessian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Having the multinomial logistic loss defined as:

$$
    L(z; y=j) = -\log[\operatorname{softmax}(z)]_j
$$
with, $$[\operatorname{softmax}(z)]_j = \frac{\exp(z_j)}{\sum^K_{k=1} \exp(z_k)}$$

How can I compute the **gradient** and the **Hessian** of **L** with respect to **z**?

Right now I have the following for the gradient of $L$ with respect to $z$:

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
      s_i & i \neq j \\
      (s_j-1) & i = j
\end{array} 
$$

And so, from my understanding, computing the Hessian will give me the following:

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
      0 & i \neq j \\
      1 & i = j
\end{array} 
$$

Leaving me with the Identity matrix.

What I need help with, is to understand if these values are correct or not.

They don't look correct, to say the least.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\big(#1\big)}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$The softmax function applied elementwise on the
$z$-vector yields the $s$-vector (or softmax vector)
$$s = \frac{e^z}{\o:e^z} \qiq S=\Diag{s}\qiq \c{ds = \LR{S-ss^T}dz}$$
Calculate the gradient of the loss function (for an unspecified $y$-vector)
$$\eqalign{
L &= -y:\log(s) \\
dL &= -y:S^{-1}ds \\
 &= S^{-1}y:\c{\LR{-ds}} \\
 &= S^{-1}y:\c{\LR{ss^T-S}dz} \\
 &= \LR{ss^T-S}S^{-1}y:dz \\
 &= \LR{s\o^T-I}y:dz \\
 &= \LR{s-y}:dz \\
\grad{L}{z}
 &= \LR{s-y} \;\doteq\; g \qquad\bR{{\rm the\;gradient}} \\
}$$
Then calculate the Hessian as the gradient of the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
dg &= \c{ds = \LR{S-ss^T}dz} \\
\grad{g}{z} &= \LR{S-ss^T} \;\doteq\; H \qquad\bR{{\rm the\;Hessian}}  \\
}$$
Now you can set $y$ to whichever one-hot vector you're interested in. Note that the Hessian is independent of $y$, so it doesn't matter which one you choose. Also note that, the term one-hot vector is not used outside of the discipline of *Machine Learning*. Instead they're referred to as the standard (or Cartesian or canonical) basis vectors and denoted as $\{e_j\}$

---

**NB:** $\;$In many of the steps above,
the matrix inner product is used
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
When applied to vectors $\bR{n=\o}$, this corresponds to the ordinary dot product, i.e.
$$a:b = a^Tb \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m a_{i}b_{i}$$

The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in an
inner product to be rearranged in many different but equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:AB &= CB^T:A = A^TC:B \\
}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your notation (probably derived from a statistics books) is horrible (as most statistics books).

In mathematical terms: let $\pi_k:\mathbf{R}^d \to \mathbf{R}$ denote the $k$th projection $\pi_k(z) = z_k.$ You want to find the first and second derivative of $L(z) = - \log\left( \dfrac{\exp(\pi_j(z))}{\sum\limits_{k = 1}^d \exp(\pi_k(z))} \right).$ Let me first rewrite $L(z)$ as follows:
$$
L(z) = \log \left( \sum\limits_{k = 1}^d \exp(\pi_k(z)) \right) - \pi_j(z).
$$
Next, notice that each $\pi_k$ is a *linear* function, which implies that its derivative at any point is just itsef: $\pi_k'(z) = \pi_k.$ Then,
$$
\begin{align}
L'(z) &= \log'\left( \sum\limits_{k = 1}^d \exp(\pi_k(z)) \right) \sum\limits_{k = 1}^d \exp'(\pi_k(z)) \pi_k - \pi_j \\
&=\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k = 1}^d \exp(\pi_k(z)) \pi_k}{\sum\limits_{k = 1}^d \exp(\pi_k(z))} - \pi_j.
\end{align}
$$
It is convenient to write this in matrix terms. Note that for any $k,$ $\pi_k(z) = z_k = c_k^\intercal z,$ where $c_k$ is the $k$th canonical vector in $\mathbf{R}^d.$ So that $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^d \exp(\pi_k(z)) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^d e^{c_k^\intercal z}.$ Thus, the matrix representation of $L$ (relative to the canonical bases of $\mathbf{R}^d$ and $\mathbf{R}$) is
$$
L'(z) = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{k = 1}^d e^{c_k^\intercal z} c_k}{\sum\limits_{k = 1}^d e^{c_k^\intercal z}} - c_j.
$$
The second derivative of $L$ is now obvious (just differentiate the previous expression relative to $z$):
$$
L''(z) = \dfrac{ \left( \sum\limits_{k = 1}^d e^{c_k^\intercal z} c_k c_k^\intercal \right) \sum\limits_{k = 1}^d e^{c_k^\intercal z} - \left( \sum\limits_{k = 1}^d e^{c_k^\intercal z} c_k \right) \left( \sum\limits_{k = 1}^d e^{c_k^\intercal z} c_k^\intercal \right) }{ \left( \sum\limits_{k = 1}^d e^{c_k^\intercal z} \right)^2 }
$$
For a given $z,$ write $s_k = s_k(z) = e^{c_k^\intercal z} = e^{z_k},$ and denote by $s$ the sum of the $s_k.$ Then
$$
L''(z) = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{k = 1}^d ss_k c_k c_k^\intercal - \sum\limits_{1 \leq a, b \leq d}^d s_as_b c_ac_b^\intercal}{ s^2 }
$$
Note that $c_ac_b^\intercal$ is a square matrix of order $d$ filled with zeroes except entry $(a, b)$ where you have a one. Thus,
$$
[L'(z)]_i = \dfrac{s_i}{s} - \delta_{i,j}
$$
and
$$
[L''(z)]_{a,b} = \delta_{a,b} \dfrac{s_a}{s} - \dfrac{s_a s_b}{s^2}.
$$